# How to disable the auto-suggestion and multiple eye icon in password field in the login form

Tags: webview2

Having two different issues which I couldn't find the solution

1. Disable the auto-suggestion of emails

It would be good to know the option for disabling auto-suggestion. Please refer the screenshot below,

[image: Auto Suggestion in Login page]

2. Multiple password view icon

I)First icon, gets disabled once I click outside then continue the password (i.e) unfocus and focus the input field

II)Second icon, I can use it once eg: click showing the password icon get disabled then I need to click outside and continue to enter the password to make it visible

Please refer the screenshot below,
[image: Multi password view]

Package we are using:

Microsoft.Web.WebView2 - 1.0.1293.44

```
public class WinFormsWebView : IBrowser
    {
        private readonly Func<Form> _formFactory;
        private BrowserOptions _options;

        public WinFormsWebView(Func<Form> formFactory)
        {
            _formFactory = formFactory;
        }

        public WinFormsWebView(string title = "Login", int width = 1024, int height = 768)
            : this(() => new Form
            {
                Name = "Login",
                Text = title,
                Width = width,
                Height = height
            })
        { }

        public async Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options, CancellationToken token = default)
        {
            _options = options;

            using (var form = _formFactory.Invoke())
            {
                using (var webView = new WebView2()
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                })
                {
                    var signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

                    var browserResult = new BrowserResult
                    {
                        ResultType = BrowserResultType.UserCancel
                    };

                    form.FormClosed += (o, e) =>
                    {
                        signal.Release();
                    };

                    webView.NavigationStarting += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        if (IsBrowserNavigatingToRedirectUri(new Uri(e.Uri)))
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;

                            browserResult = new BrowserResult()
                            {
                                ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success,
                                Response = new Uri(e.Uri).AbsoluteUri
                            };

                            signal.Release();
                            form.Close();
                        }
                    };

                    try
                    {
                        form.Controls.Add(webView);
                        webView.Show();

                        form.Show();

                        var webView2Environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, @"C:\temp");

                        // Initialization
                        await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webView2Environment);

                        // Delete existing Cookies so previous logins won't remembered
                        webView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.DeleteAllCookies();

                       webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsPasswordAutosaveEnabled = false;
                        webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsGeneralAutofillEnabled = false;

                        // Navigate
                        webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(_options.StartUrl);

                        await signal.WaitAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        form.Hide();
                        webView.Hide();
                    }

                    return browserResult;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsBrowserNavigatingToRedirectUri(Uri uri)
        {
            return uri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(_options?.EndUrl);
        }
    }
```

Tried with the already available microsoft package : Microsoft.Web.WebView2 - 1.0.1293.44